# Javascript async await - why is my await not stopping execution of following code until resolved?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I know there are already many questions about promises but I dont understand in my specific case why an await does not stop the execution of following code. In my case its about sending push notifications but mostly about the async/await inside the code.

```
const NotificationsService = {
    async notifyFollowers(followers, message) {
        let pushTokens = [];
        const {title, body} = message;
         followers.map(async (follower) => {
            

> console.log("called 1st 4 times as 4 followers")

             const notification = await this.createNotification(follower._id, message);
         

>   //called 3rd / last

            console.log("follower.expoPushToken")
            if (!pushTokens.includes(follower.expoPushToken)) {
                pushTokens.push(follower.expoPushToken);
            };

> if I put it here instead, it all works as executed

           // const notification = await this.createNotification(follower._id, message);
            if (follower._id.toString() === notification.to.toString()) {
                ...
            }
        });
       

>  //called 2nd

        console.log("is this line reached?")
        this.sendPushNotification(pushTokens, title, body);
    },

    async createNotification (to, message) {
        const notification = await Notification.findOneAndUpdate({to:to},
            {$push: {...}}
        )
        return notification;
   },
}
```

so my question is: Shouldnt this await

```
const notification = await this.createNotification(follower._id, message)
```

make the execution of following code:

```
console.log("follower.expoPushToken")
            if (!pushTokens.includes(follower.expoPushToken)) {
                pushTokens.push(follower.expoPushToken);
            };
```

stop until promise is resolved?

Comment: `array#map` with async functions will not wait between array items, it will just generate an array of promises. Use a regular for loop.

Comment: thank you. can i also ask: why is this line:  if (follower._id.toString() === notification.to.toString()) { reached after "console.log("follower.expoPushToken")" and I assume after notification resolves (?!) ? Because the if statement isnt async so shouldnt it be executed earlier?

Comment: You should post a real [mcve]. I'm not clear if the `> // comment` sections are indicating different functions w/ code omitted, or what.